# Unable to run the React-Redux project. Webpack error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

> $ npm start

**｢wds｣:Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'modulesDirectories'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, concord?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
   -> Options for the resolver**

*webpack.config.js*

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
        modulesDirectories: [
            'node_modules'
          ]     
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader','css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html'
    })],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    externals: {
        // global app config object
        config: JSON.stringify({
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'
        })
    }
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "react-redux-registration-login-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/cornflourblue/react-redux-registration-login-example.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "history": "^4.6.3",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning states, `resolve.modulesDirectories` is not a valid property. It was an option in Webpack version 1, but has since version 2 been renamed to `resolve.modules`.

So change your config to:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
  modules: [
    'node_modules'
  ]     
},
```

---

See: https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/

> `resolve.root`, `resolve.fallback`, `resolve.modulesDirectories`
>
> These options were replaced by a single option resolve.modules. See [resolving](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) for more usage.